# Build failed because of react native reanimated 2

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I install react native reanimated 2 according to its installation doc. But when I run project for android build, I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'lib/x86_64/libreactnativejni.so' from inputs:
      - D:\ReactBootCamp_RASAHR\Bootcamp Main Projects\ReactNative\SecondVersion\Fooductor\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\.transforms\1ebd6d22f25011a79a18acd12f297fc9\transformed\jetified-react-native-reanimated-65-hermes\jni
      - C:\Users\Kavosh\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\156e8e6ad84734ffd5fbff137e92dae0\transformed\jetified-react-native-0.65.1\jni
     If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
     https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Plase use reanimated version 2.3 series with RN 0.65+

Comment: What is your react-native version?

Comment: react-native version --> 0.65 and reanimated --> 2.3.0-beta.2   @ridvanaltun